# Recursively get background color of element fails

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to get the background color of a logotype in a webpage.
What I will do is to clone the logo and put the clone in another div that should be of the right color.

The document looks like:

```
<div>
    <div class="foo">
        <div id="start">
           Find background for this div
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="on_find_color_clicked()">
    find color
</button>
```

What I have tried is:

```
function on_find_color_clicked()
{
  var background = get_background_of($('#start'));

  alert("the background is " + background);
}

function get_background_of(element)
{
  var parent = element.parent();
  var value = element.css('background');

  var result;
  if (is_null_or_empty(value))
  {
    result = parent != null
      ? get_background_of(parent) : "";
  }
  else
    result = value;    

  return result;
}

function is_null_or_empty(value)
{
  return value == null || value == '';
}
```

I get this error:

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]
```

in

```
return window.getComputedStyle( elem, null );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MCC9L/5/

Comment: try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MCC9L/13/) it's working fine

Comment: Pranav: Yes, it works, make an answer of this comment, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the color you should ask for it, instead of the entire `background` properties, by changing `var value = element.css('background');` to `var value = element.css('backgroundColor')`

But the bigger issue is that `function is_null_or_empty(value) { return value == null || value == ''; }` should be `function is_null_or_empty(value) { return value == null || value == '' || value==='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' || value==='transparent'; }` since an empty `backgroundColor` can return as `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` or `transparent`. Otherwise it won't be triggered.

**something like this**

```
function on_find_color_clicked() {
    var background = get_background_of($('#start'));
    alert("the background is " + background);
}

function get_background_of(element) {
    var parent = element.parent();
    var value = element.css('backgroundColor');
    var result;
    if (is_null_or_empty(value)) {
        result = parent && parent != null ? get_background_of(parent) : "";
    } else { result = value; }
    return result;
}

function is_null_or_empty(value) {
    return value == null || value == '' || value==='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' || value==='transparent';
}
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/USNaZ/

Comment: "the background is transparent" in firefox

Comment: However, I have came to a solution

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

http://jsfiddle.net/MCC9L/27/

```
function on_find_color_clicked() {
    var background = get_background_of($('#start'));

    alert("the background is " + background);
}

function get_background_of(element) {
    var parent = element.parent();
    var value = element.css('background-color');

    if (value.indexOf("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") != -1) {
        value = get_background_of(parent);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: I got "the background is transparent"

Comment: Hmm...browser differences? I'm on Chrome and it returns "the background is rgb(255, 0, 255)".

Comment: Using firefox, interesting

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.css("background-color")` instead of `.css("background")`